# Select based on complex conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

Please tell me the SQL statement to SELECT under the following conditions for the test table shown below.

test table layout

```
ID  KEY     VALUE
1   FOO     A
2   BAR     B
3   HOGE    C
4
5
・・・
```

1. If VALUE of ID = 1 and KEY = FOO is equal to VALUE of ID = 2 and KEY = BAR, VALUE of ID = 3 and KEY = HOGE is returned.
2. If VALUE with ID = 1 and KEY = FOO and VALUE with ID = 2 and KEY = BAR are **not equal**, VALUE with ID = 3 and KEY = HOGE is returned.

Comment: Add a few more rows with sample data. Also specify the expected result. And show us your current query attempt.

Comment: ID KEY  VALUE
1 FOO  A
2 BAR  A
3 HOGE C
1 FOO  D
2 BAR  E

Comment: Hey, not as a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: 1.  value C return

Comment: I might be wrong, but - as far as I understood, you want to select 3 HOGE in any case. Conditions 1 and 2 seem to be equal (with slightly different wording), but the point is "are equal" and "are not equal" in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

Condition 1 and 2 are mutually exclusive: if 1 is true then 2 is not true, and vice versa.  In both cases the desired outcome is ...

> value C return

... so actually this query satisfies the requirement:

```
select value
from your_table
where ID = 3 
and KEY = 'HOGE'
```

No doubt this is not the answer you want. Please you need to clarify your question.